Is it possible to restrict access to some services but not others?
Good morning. Is there a way to, within a project, grant access to a group of users to a single service, but not to the rest (which would be restricted)?
Let me give you an example: I have a project in which I need a group of defined users to be able to access the Artifacts, but not have access to the Boards, Pipelines, etc.
Is this possible? I'm doing tests and I can't find a way.
If this were possible, could it also be applied to an organization globally (and not just project by project)?
1.- I have created a security group (Organization settings > Security > Permissions), and have denied all permissions to it.
2.- Organization settings > Group rules: I've added the group to a couple of projects
3.- In each of those projects, in Artifacts, I have added the group

Currently, Azure DevOps only supports enabling or disabling a service at the project-level. If you want such a feature at user-level, you can submit a feature request on the Azure DevOps Developer Community.


I have a project in which I need a group of defined users to be able to access the Artifacts, but not have access to the Boards, Pipelines, etc.

As a workaround, you can combine access level and specific permissions.
When assign users with Stakeholder access, they will experience limited features at organization-level. For example, they can only see the services as shown below. Learn the detailed supported features from Supported access levels.

For Boards and Pipelines, you can use Project-level permissions and Pipeline-level permissions to restrict users' access to these services as much as possible, but it is impossible to achieve 100% restriction.

No, you can't really do this easily in Azure DevOps. With customizing the default permissions beyond recognition, you may be able to come close, but I highly recommend you don't do that.

To restrict access on the project level, you may:

Update permissions of your project area level:



Update permissions on the root of pipelines



The same for the repos:


